# Count and print images from URL

Tags: image, scala, apache-spark, url

This is my first time using Spark/Scala and I am lost.

I am suppose to write a program that takes in a URL and outputs the number of images and the name of the image file.

So I was able to get the image count.  I am doing this all in the command prompt which is making it quite difficult to go back and edit my def without out retyping the whole thing.  Is there a better alternative.  It took me quite a while just to get Spark/Scala working (I would of like to u PySpark but was unable to get them to communicate)

scala> def URLcount(url : String) : String = {

```
 | var html = scala.io.Source.fromURL(url).mkString

 | var list = html.split("\n").filter(_ != "")

 | val rdds = sc.parallelize(list)

 | val count = rdds.filter(_.contains("img")).count()

 | return("There are " + count + " images at the " + url + " site.")

 | }
```

URLcount: (url: String)String

scala> URLcount("https://www.yahoo.com/")

res14: String = There are 9 images at the https://www.yahoo.com/ site.

So I'm assuming after I parallelize the list I should be about to apply a filter and create a list of all the strings that contain "img src"
How would I create such list and then print it line by line to display the image urls?

Comment: "Is there a better alternative" - You can write Spark programs in any IDE, Jupyter, or Zeppelin

Answer (score 0):

I don't sure it is great solution for parsing HTML via Spark. I think that Spark created for big data (while it is general purpose). I did not find any easy way to parse HTML through Spark (but I easy find it for both XML and JSON). It is mean that in this case you will print a very long string, because HTML pages are often compressed. Anyway, for this page your program will print lines like this:

```
<p>So I'm assuming after I parallelize the list I should be about to apply a filter and create a list of all the strings that contain "img src"
```

I can advice you use Jsoup:

```scala
  val yahoo = Jsoup.connect("https://www.yahoo.com").get
  val images = yahoo.select("img[src]")
  images.forEach(println)
```

You can use Spark for other purposes.

PS: I found 39 image tags with src attribute on https://www.yahoo.com. It is very easy to got error if you don't use good HTML parser.
Another way: prepare your data and than use Spark.

Sorry for my English.

Comment: Jsoup can be inserted into Spark, although it would only make sense if you had a large list of urls to parse, all similarly